# How to understand this formula?

Tags: real-analysis, fake-proofs

We have
$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(a_n+b_n)=a+b$

if  $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=a$  and  $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}b_n=b$

Why is this wrong:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}1=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}+ \frac{1}{n}+ \cdots + \frac{1}{n}\right)=n\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$?

Comment: Bringing a constant out is not the same as bringing a variable out.  Would you argue that $\lim_{n\to \infty}n=\lim_{n\to \infty}n\times 1=n\lim_{n\to \infty}1=n$?  That's a variable, not a real number, even an extended one.

Answer (score 2):

You have, as a proven theorem, that if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ exists and is equal to $a$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$ exists and is equal to $b$, then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n+b_n) = a+b
$$
Analagous theorems are true for finite sums of any size, e.g., $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n+b_n+c_n + d_n) = a+b+c+d$.

You **don't** have a theorem that says

If for all $i\in\Bbb{N}: \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n^{(i)}$ exists and is equal to $x^{(i)}$, then 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(  \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_n^{(i)} \right) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty x^{(i)}
$$
which in words would say that you can always interchange the order of summing and taking the limit, even in infinite sums.

If you **did** have that as a theorem then you could use it to validate your "proof" that $1=0$.  In fact, your observation is a proof by contradiction that sometimes interchanging the sum and limit operations gives different answers.

Congratulations on discovering this important "you must not assume this" fact on your own!

Comment: Many thanks for this!